# Explorer using in my app

Tags: android, audio, filesystems

When i click on the button, programm asking which file manager i want to use (or Dropbox etc). Then i choose, for example, .mp3 file. How i can tell my programm to start this .mp3, when i'll need it? How to remember this choosed file?

```
ring_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent_for_ring_button = new Intent();
                intent_for_ring_button.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                File file = new File(REPORTS_DIRECTORY);
                intent_for_ring_button.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file),"application/file");
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent_for_ring_button,"Open folder"), 0);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
Uri myUri = Uri.parse(entry.getFile());
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(myUri, "audio/*");
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(intent);
```